# Global variable vs local variable assignment in terms of efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, performance, oop

Which way is better in terms of efficiency, assuming that `m_eligibleCustomers` in the code below is reasonably big to have an impact on efficiency.

Declare it globally and assign value to the variable when the object is created and let it stay until the object goes out of scope. Or assign the value only inside the methods, (let's say 3 methods need it out of 20), not all of them might be called, could belong to different event code, so that the memory is freed up as soon as the method is out of scope.

I personally like doing it global, assigning value on the first use, and reusing, but if object is reasonably large, would that be a right decision? More I think, I feel declaring with in a scope of method seems to be a good idea. What would be a better option to choose in a scenario like above?

```
   internal class Program
   {
    private DataSet m_CustomerSet;
    private IEnumerable<Customer> m_eligibleCustomers;

    public Program()
    {
        m_CustomerSet = GetDataSetFromCache();
        m_eligibleCustomers = GetEligibleCustomers(customerSet);
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MethodA(eligibleCustomers); //OR MethodA(customerSet) and do calculation with in the method 
        //and object is destroyed as soon as the method is completed
        MethodB();
        MethodC();
        MethodD();
        MethodE();
        MethodF();
        MethodG(eligibleCustomers);
        MethodH();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Do *not* entertain "efficiency" here at all (in terms of local vs "global" variables). Go back to the start. Write clean code. Thanks, and have a good day!

Comment: Even in terms of cleaner, which one do you think is more readable? If proper naming conventions are followed and variables are named properly, I can see both of them being equally clean code. In terms of reusability, sure the global way is preferred. For this one time, could you please consider that  you have to take a performance into consideration?

Comment: (I am not trying to imply that it is appropriate to keep about dozens of extra objects representing the same data, especially for larger objects or slow reconstruction methods, but rather that this *lifetime* management not be choice between using a local variable and a member variable: it is about lifetimes, however they are maintained. Variables facilitate how such objects are kept-reachable/accessed, but there is no problem passing an object in a member variable, or variable in the current scope, to a function for use as a local variable, etc.)

Comment: (As for when keeping shared/cached data is appropriate - and/or how it is injected/created, safely modified, and appropriately disposed of if relevant - there is no one answer to that. My general recommendation is to minimize the effective scope of such and avoid relying on the objects' state as much as possible, which also favors supplying objects as parameters to internal methods and writing "pure" functions.)

Comment: If the data might not be needed you might want to consider _lazy initialization_.

Comment: I would appreciate if I am told the reason behind the down votes...

Answer (score 0):

Yes keep it global because you will need to call DB every time , but gobal variable is old school , use cache to store such objects especially if it is web application so you can set expire date , etc

Comment: In my scenario, I would be reading from cache, and then perform operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want efficiency go and get C or Assembler. Otherwise write your algorithms efficiently. In worst case give up on recursion and replace it by a (maybe more complicated) loop - BUT NEVER micro optimise these kind of things.

Write the code in a clean way so that you will be able to understand it in a year, that gives you much more value than any tick of performance you might gain by which ever solution might be by 0,0001% faster.

Comment: "If you wan efficiency go and get C or Assembler." What if your project has already been running on a particular domain for years? With proper naming conventions followed and methods/variables appropriately named, I can see the code being clean and understandable either way.

Comment: if you really believe that it will make a change - go ahead, benchmark it. I've optimised C# code. Usually I had to optimise my colleagues algorithms or make sure that they use the proper types for the proper task. This improved the performance by several %. (and I've mentioned it above) - I've never had time to optimise for such things - that's why my suggestion, similar to everyone elses - don't do it, you won't get anything out of it

Comment: Thank-you. I like your words on your comment than in your answer. Appreciated.